# Can Adobe be set to default to open all PDFs at 100% zoom?

Tags: adobe-reader

I open and close many PDFs at work every day. Is it possible to have Adobe's default settings saved so that all PDFs open at 100% zoom (rather than fitting to screen--most open at over 100%)?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Edit -> Preferences -> Page Display -> Default Layout and Zoom (Zoom: Drop down to 100%)

Comment: This needs to be done from Adobe Reader running as a separate instance, rather than within the plugin for Firefox, IE etc.

Answer (score 2):

If the accepted answer doesn't work then there is another setting that you may have to change as I did:

[image]

Citing Source: http://www.technipages.com/adobe-reader-change-default-zoom-setting

Comment: German: Bearbeiten -> Voreinstellungen -> Ein-/Ausgabehilfe -> Seitenanzeige überschreiben -> Immer Zoom-Einstellung verwenden -> Fenstergrösse